# Cannot end a section without first starting one in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

```
    @extends('main')
    @foreach ($hotel as $hotel)
    @foreach ($city as $city)
    @section('title'," $hotel->hotel - $city->city")
    @endsection
    @section('content')
      {{-- Header --}}
      <div style="background-image:url('../img/{{ $hotel->id }}.jpg'); height:400px; background-size:cover;">
          <div class="container">
            @include('partials._nav')
          <div class="row">
            <center>
              <h2>
                <div class="col-md-12 hotel-name">
                {{ $hotel->hotel }}
              <p class="city">
              </h2>
                  {{ $city->city }}
                @endforeach
              </p>
            </div>
          </center>
          </div>
          </div>
          {{-- End Search bar --}}


          </div>
       </div>
       {{-- Header End here --}}
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      {{-- Modal Closed --}}
      <div class="container">
        {{-- Tab Start here --}}
      <div class="tabs">

        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Menu</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Comments <span class="disqus-comment-count" data-disqus-identifier="article_1_identifier"></span></a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Photo</a></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <h3>Contact No.</h3>
                <p class="contactno">{{ $hotel->contactno }}</p>
                <p class="remark">{{ $hotel->remark }}</p>

                <h3>Cuisines</h3>
                <p class="cuisines">{{ $hotel->cuisines }}</p>

                <h3>Cost</h3>
                <p class="cost">{{ $hotel->cost }}</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <h3>Opening Hours</h3>
                <p class="hours">{{ date('h:ia', strtotime($hotel->openfrom)) }} - {{ date('h:ia', strtotime($hotel->opento)) }}</p>

                <h3>Address</h3>
                <p class="address">{{ $hotel->address }}</p>
                <div id="map" style="width:150px;height:100px;"></div>

              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <h3>Highlights</h3>
                <p class="highlight">{{ $hotel->highlight }}</p>

                <h3>Featured in Collection</h3>
                <p class="featured">{{ $hotel->featured }}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">
            <table class="table">
              <tr>
                <th>#</th>
              <th>Dish</th>
              <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
              @foreach ($menu as $menu)
              <tr>
                <td>{{ $menu->id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $menu->dish_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $menu->price }}</td>
              </tr>
              @endforeach
            </table>
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">

            {{-- Disqus Start from here --}}
            <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
              <script>

              /**
              *  RECOMMENDED CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT AND UNCOMMENT THE SECTION BELOW TO INSERT DYNAMIC VALUES FROM YOUR PLATFORM OR CMS.
              *  LEARN WHY DEFINING THESE VARIABLES IS IMPORTANT: https://disqus.com/admin/universalcode/#configuration-variables*/
              /*
              var disqus_config = function () {
              this.page.url = PAGE_URL;  // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
              this.page.identifier = PAGE_IDENTIFIER; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable
              };
              */
              (function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
              var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
              s.src = '//gobumpr.disqus.com/embed.js';
              s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
              (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
              })();
              </script>
              <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
          </div>
          {{-- Disqus End Here --}}

          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings"></div>
        </div>

      </div>


    {{-- Tab End Here --}}

    </div>
    @endsection
    @section('javascript')
      <script>
    function myMap() {
      var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
      var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng({{ $hotel->directions }}),
        zoom: 10
      }
      var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=myMap"></script>
    <script id="dsq-count-scr" src="//gobumpr.disqus.com/count.js" async></script>
    @endforeach
    {{-- <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDu9JV__AvYU6auWV-QsJuV82TnLtrytm0&callback=initMap" async defer></script> --}}
    @endsection
```

[image]

I am getting this:

> Error:: 
>   ErrorException in Factory.php line 587:
>   Cannot end a section without first starting one. (View: E:\Other\gobumpr\resources\views\pages\select.blade.php)

Answer (score 6):

In here

```
@section('title'," $hotel->hotel - $city->city")
@endsection
```

you don't gonna need an `@endsection` since you supply the content for the `title`.

The 2nd argument of `@section()` consider as the content for the `@section()`

Simply use `@section('title'," $hotel->hotel - $city->city")`

Comment: After removing that @endsection part I am still getting that error

Comment: Make sure you do a `php artisan view:clear` to clear view cache, as the error could be getting from a cache.

Comment: :( Is it generating from the same location

Comment: yes even I remove @end section from another file too.

Comment: You need to properly structure your codes. In your example you have put `@endsection` and `@endforeach` here and there (Ex: your last @endforeach` where does it starts?). You need to really take good care of your code :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `@section('section_name', 'section_content')` syntax, your section's content is "section_content". There is no need to close such section with `@endsection`.

Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#extending-a-layout

Comment: After removing that @endsection part I am still getting that error

Answer (score 1):

> @section('javascript')
>         
>       function myMap() {
>         var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
>         var mapOptions = {
>           center: new google.maps.LatLng({{ $hotel->directions }}),
>           zoom: 10
>         }
>         var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
>       }
>       
>       
>       
>       @endforeach
>       {{--  --}}
>       @endsection

The @endsection needs to be before the @endforeach.

Comment: I agree, also there one more `@endforeach` in the beggining that, I suspect, shouldn't be where it is.

Answer (score 1):

removing `@endsection` will solve the problem. I'm trying to add title page with `@yield('title')` in `<title></title>` and provide with `@section('title', 'pageTitle')` without `@endsection`.

Answer (score 1):

you defenetly forget the'@' before the word section

Comment: Please elaborate. Nothing in the code shown by OP is a word "section" without an "@" before. You also seem to contradict more than one of the existing upvoted answers. In this situation even more than anyway on StackOverflow you should really augment your answer with some explanation. I am not saying you are wrong, but your answer is in stark contrast to the others.

Comment: Also, you would do everyone a favor, including yourself, if you'd take the time to take the [tour] and read [answer].

Comment: Perfect English is not required on StackOverflow. But in case of this post a little more grammar would clarify things. For example "you ... forget" is grammatically imprecise, not really a problem. But it could mean "you ... forgot", i.e. describing the relevant mistake. Or it could mean "you ... should forget/delete", meaning the recommended solution. I.e. in this case grammar would allow to tell the difference between two absolutely contradicting interpretations of your post. Using capitalisation, spelling and punctuation is just for prettiness and readability, not strictly needed.

Comment: If grammar, spelling, punctution is not your strong point (and I really feel with you) then please use more words. Maybe even one or two additional sentences.

Answer (score 0):

try to delete the @endsection after the section('title') it will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

use @stop or @endsection (only one) in a blade template not both.
You should use  @stop or @endsection  after @section
For example

It'll work

```
        @section('testing')
        <h1>kjfdgjkfdgfd kjgkdfhgdljkfs hgdfhgjk</h1>
        @endsection
```

It'll not work

```
        @section('testing')
        <h1>kjfdgjkfdgfd kjgkdfhgdljkfs hgdfhgjk</h1>
        @endsection      
        @stop
```