# Handle Laravel Blade View::render() exception

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a helper function for rendering a dynamic view that looks something like

```
public function renderDynamicView($path, $data)
{
    return View::make($path, $data)->render();
}
```

Now if there's an exception occurred within the provided view (e.g. missing information in the supplied `$data`), the code will just crap out. How do I put a generic try catch around this to render a default view for such case? I've tried something like

```
public function renderDynamicView($path, $data)
{
    try
    {
        return View::make($path, $data)->render();
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        return View::make('broken')->render();
    }
}
```

The above somehow results in `Cannot end a section without first starting one.` exception.

Comment: post your views

Comment: Most likely an error in your view, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41651197/cannot-end-a-section-without-first-starting-one-in-laravel

Comment: Yes I'm sure there's an issue with the view supplied by `$path` (e.g. something could be null). Thus I want to generically catch all exception and render a default view, in this case `broken` is just a blank blade file.